# AJAX not posting data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, post

Having an issue trying to figure out why my AJAX isn't posting to my PHP. I can tell it's loading the PHP code, and if I remove references to the keyword check and parameter in the query it runs fine and loads all task_types form the DB. But specifying that it needs to match the input value, it doesn't work because it doesn't POST to the PHP. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="task_type" id="task_type" value="" />
<div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#task_type').keyup(function(){       
        console.log($(this).val());     
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/ajax/ajax_search_task_types.php',
            data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),               
            success: function(data){
                console.log('hello'+data);
                $('#suggesstion-box').show();
                $('#suggesstion-box').html(data);
                $("#task_type").css("background","#FFF");
            }
        });
    });
}); 

function selectCountry(val) {
    $("#task_type").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

**AJAX_SEARCH_TASK_TYPES.PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
require_once('../../lib.inc.php');
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT task_type FROM task WHERE task_type LIKE '".$db->prep($_POST['keyword'])."%' AND task_type <> 'Unassigned' AND user_id = ".$db->prep($user_id)." ORDER BY task_type";
$resT = $db->query($query,'assoc'); 
if(!empty($resT)) {
?>
<ul id="task-list">
<?php
foreach($resT as $task_type_value) { ?>
    <li onClick="selectTask('<?php echo $task_type_value['task_type']; ?>');"><?php echo $task_type_value['task_type']; ?></li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

---

**UPDATE 6/7/2020**

I did some further testing and discovered that some code my htaccess is preventing the values to POST. I have no idea why or how to fix. Any ideas?

Here's the bit that's causing the issue:

```
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Comment: isset($_POST['keyword']) return true ?

Comment: Is `$user_id` well defined when you execute your query ?

Comment: @mR.Rian it returns false

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz yes it is.

Comment: @Dharman thanks for the warning. I will look more into that!

Comment: The browser follows such an external redirect by switching the request method to GET, so you “lose” your POST data in such a case. By why are you letting that redirect happen in the first place? You appear to have a setup, that “hides” the `.php` extension from script URLs - so _why_ is your AJAX request still going to a URL that _has_ one at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test it, but try changing this in your JS file:

```js
data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
```

To this:

```
data: {keyword: $(this).val(),
```

And I would highly recommend adding this line to the beginning of your PHP file:

```php
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn, $_POST['keyword'] );
```

The line above prevents an SQL injection.
Again though, since I'm currently on mobile, I can't test it. But if it doesn't work, *please* tell me and I'll try to see whats wrong with my code.